# Selecting a sub row cell in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

While selecting one entire row we can use `={Sheet1!1:1}`. I am interested in knowing how do we select a sub row starting from B1 and till the end. Is there any way to do so without using Apps Script?

Edit 1: THe solution provided by @Marios works but let me just add a modification to my problem. I want to use the columns for column validation as shown below:

[image]

Whatever was suggested in answer works in general but I wanted to use that criterion for data validation dropdown. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: For documentation reasons, please accept my answer if it solved your question. Otherwise, provide me your feedback. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reaching out, what you suggested works well in case of normal entry but what I actually wanted to achieve is the image I have added in the question. Sorry for the confusion. Please do let me know in case it works here.

Comment: in the data validation form you can only use spefic ranges if you are referring to subsets. So what you ask is not possible.

Comment: Check my updated answer. I suggest you to use my solution in your sheet, and then grab the full row from there.

Comment: Thanks so much @Marios... that's exactly what I was looking for! Is there anyway to hide the data in first row!?!?

Comment: Just select the full row and click hide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
={Sheet1!B1:1}
```

### Update:

[image: example]